# Select multiple points on scatterplot, save selection to new table

Tags: r, gis

I have a very large data set (~250,000 records) that I have used to create a linear model.  I have plotted predicted vs. actual

[image: Predicted vs actual with some labels in area of interest].

I tried to use identify() to select the two cluster of values near the center of the graph and coord() to identify them.  There are a few problems here: 1)There are many, many more points in those clusters than I can click on and identify individually, and 2)I need to know ALL of them, select all of them somehow with out selecting any others, and subset my data to just those points.

This model was created using a satellite image paired with ancillary spatial data.  Each entry in the table corresponds to a particular point on the map.  I need to identify where these two clusters are located on the map.  My data frame includes the FID (which I can use to link back to the map), the original predictor, the response, and my predicted values.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: It sounds like what you need is cluster analysis.    The simplest version of this is kmeans, but what will work for you will depend on the nature of your data.  if you are clicking on points on a graph,  I assume that there is a usable two-dimensional representation.  Could you at least show us the graph?

Comment: I included that in the original question, did it not show up? It is the link "predicted vs actual with some labels in area of interest".

Comment: It is there.   My error.

Comment: I am slightly surprised that you describe this as two clusters rather than 4.  For this data, kmeans is probably not so good.  I would recommend using hclust - the hierarchical clustering algorithm   and use method="single".

Comment: They're already divided such that you could just subset to predicted values greater than -10 and actual values less than -7, depending on what your use-case is.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say 4 clusters, you're right.  I'm just hung-up on those two in the middle at the moment.  I will look at hclust.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you only want to select the data in this specific plot and the data structure is something like data.frame(x= , y=), you can look at subset the data frame based on the the regions you want to select. For example if you want the bottom right cluster you could say data[ x<(-5) & x>(-10) &y<(-11) & y>(-15) ,]